# Assigning ndarray in cython to new variable very slow? Or what is going on here?

Tags: python, cython

I am fairly new to cython and I am wondering why the following takes very long:

```
cpdef test(a):
    cdef  np.ndarray[dtype=int] b
    for i in range(10):
        b=a
```

```
a=np.array([1,2,3],dtype=int)
t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(test.test, a))
print(t.timeit(1000000))
-> 0.5446977 Seconds
```

If i comment out the cdef declaration this is done in no-time. If i declare "a" as np.ndarray in the function header nothing changes. Also, id(a) == id(b) so no new objects are created.

Similar behaviour can be observed when calling a function that takes many ndarray as args, e.g.

```
cpdef foo(np.ndarray a, np.ndarray b,np.ndarray c, ..... )
```

Can anybody help me? What am i missing here?

Edit:
I noticed the following:

This is slow:

```
cpdef foo(np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] a,np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] b,np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] c ) :
        return
```

This is faster:

```
def foo(np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] a,np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] b,np.ndarray[dtype=int,ndim=1] c ) :
    return
```

This is the fastest

```
cpdef foo( a,b,c ) :
    return
```

The function foo() is called very frequently (many million times) in my project from many different locations and does some calculus with the three numpy arrays (however, it doesnt change their content).

I basically need the speed of knowing the data-type inside of the arrays while also having a very low function-call overead. What would be the most adequate solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b = a` generates a bunch of type checking that needs to identify whether the type of `a` is actually an `ndarray` and makes sure it exports the buffer protocol with an appropriate element type. In exchange for this one-off cost you get fast indexing of single elements.

If you're not doing indexing of single elements then typing as `np.ndarray` is literally pointless and you're pessimizing your code. If you are doing this indexing then you can get significant optimizations.

> If i comment out the cdef declaration this is done in no-time.

This is often a sign that the C compiler has realized the entire function does nothing and optimized it out completely. And therefore your measurement *may* be meaningless.

> `cpdef foo(np.ndarray a, np.ndarray b,np.ndarray c, ..... )`

*just* specifying the type as `np.ndarray` without specifying the element dtype usually gains you very little, and is probably not worthwhile.

---

If you have a function that you're calling millions of times then it is likely that the input arrays come from somewhere, and can be pre-typed, probably with less frequency. For example they might come by taking slices from a larger array?

The newer memoryview syntax (`int[:]`) is quick to slice, so for example if you already have a 2D memoryview (`int[:,:] x`) it's very quick to generate a 1D memoryview from it with (e.g. `x[:,0]`), and it's quick to pass existing memoryviews into a `cdef` function with memoryview arguments. (Note that (a) I'm just unsure if all of this applies to `np.ndarray` too, and (b) seeing up a fresh memoryview is likely to be about the same cost an an `np.ndarray` so I'm only suggesting using them because I know slicing is quick).

Therefore my main suggestion is to move the typing outwards to try to reduce the number of fresh initializations of these typed arrays. If that isn't possible then I think you may be stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatley, i am still not sure how i can solve my problem. I added some more information to the question. I would be super happy if you could help me out there as well! :)

Comment: I've added a bit of a suggestion. However it involves a bit of guesswork about what you're actually doing. If this doesn't apply then you may be stuck

Comment: What do you mean by pre-typing? The type of the array is known at the time I am calling the function. 
Two of the arrays are made of simply additions, the third array is simply a paramater vector. I simply dont understand why theres such a huge overhead in calling the function

Comment: I just mean making sure the values are typed in the outer function that calls `foo`. At least for typed memoryviews the cost of passing a typed memoryview from a variable that's already known to be a memoryview is cheap.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually the solution. I made a mistake declaring the input variables